# I'm developing asp .net Web API to use it in my Android app,

Tags: java, android, .net

I'm developing restful web service using asp.net Web API to use it in my Android app.

and here what I get when I run my API

```
[
  {
    "id": 41,
    "firstName": "ahmed",
    "lastName": "jallad",
    "gender": "male",
    "salary": 6000,
    "img": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\hi.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 46,
    "firstName": "ali",
    "lastName": "ali",
    "gender": "male ",
    "salary": 5000,
    "img": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\hi.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 47,
    "firstName": "wael",
    "lastName": "wael",
    "gender": "male",
    "salary": 6000,
    "img": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\hi.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "firstName": "sara",
    "lastName": "sara",
    "gender": "female",
    "salary": 5000,
    "img": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\hi.png"
  },
  {
    "id": 49,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "gender": null,
    "salary": null,
    "img": "C:\\Users\\ahmed\\Desktop\\hi.png"
  }
]
```

I'm storing the path of the image in SQL database, and here is .net code

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string gender = "ALL")
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            int a = 0;
            switch (gender.ToLower())
            {
                case "all":

                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.ToList());
                case "male":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "male").ToList());
                case "female":
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entities.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender.ToLower() == "female").ToList());
                default:
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "value for gender must be Male, Femle or ALL. " + gender + " is not valid");
            }
        }
    }
```

my question is how can open the image from its path when I call from an android application?

thanks in advance

Comment: You should really avoid returning the local paths in your response.  Not only will it not work on other peoples' machines, it's a security vulnerability because it tells potential attackers about your machine.  Instead, start by returning a URL for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815131/joe-c

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815131/joe-c do u have any idea how can start that

Comment: Do you have a new endpoint for images? (That is a rhetorical question.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815131/joe-c lol that's funny, I'm new to this technology and I don't have endpoint for them, any articles or posts I can learn how to make endpoints ??

Comment: You already have an endpoint for returning the JSON...

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: so what is missing if I already have it, can u just explain to me steps to make my api working fine https://stackoverflow.com/users/6815131/joe-c

Comment: @ahmedjallad You are using the wrong way to tag a user. You should use @ followed by the name of the user; for Joe it'd be `@JoeC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use third party libraries like [Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/)

It's pretty straight forward. Check their sample for more info

Do note you will require a valid url to successfully load an image into `ImageView`

```
GlideApp.with(this)
    .load("http://someAwesomepic")
    .into(imageView);
```

You can also use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), which is another very awesome library to do the similar job

Both the libraries are very flexible and can help you get your job done

Adding to Joe C comment, you need to create a dedicated directory for Images which can be publicly accessible. Store all your images into this directory.

Now in your database just store the image name with a path eg `/images/IMG_123.jpg`

When building the response append the base url with the above path

Comment: I have my image path not the url, is it still fine ?

Comment: Image Path needs to be converted into a valid url. This url will be pointing to a image file which can be publicly available.

Comment: Totally agree with Joe C, to not store local path to image

Comment: yea I got the idea why I should not use the image path, do you know how to convert the image path to url, and it will save my life lol, thank u https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336154/rinavrinav

Comment: Edited my answer, please check

Comment: Happy to Help :)